# pass an object inside ejs include statement

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I need to pass an object inside an ejs include statement. I found a couple of questions on the same issue but I get a weird error when i do the following,

```
<div>
<%- include (folder/index , {"user": user}) %>
</div>
```

I get,

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/views/(folder/index.ejs'
```

Any idea why i get a enoent when i pass the object inline ?

if i simply do,

```
<%- include folder/index %>
```

this works

but i need to pass user object to index. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you insert space after include, EJS will use include preprocessor directives (`<% include folder/index %>`); Although they are still supported, the new syntax is like the following:

```
<div>
  <%- include('folder/index', {user: user}) %>
</div>
```

(See [includes Documentation](https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes))

Answer (score 0):

found a solution...
Yes. I missed the obvious.

```
var json_tmp = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(pass_object) %>');
```